# Need better Java application deployment strategy

Tags: java, swing, deployment

I have various Java Swing applications that are used by multiple users. My deployment strategy is to locate the .jar file on a network share, and users create shortcuts to that file. When the user launches an application, the file is copied to their machine and executed locally. This method allows for a single copy of the code and easy updating.

The problem is that I can't update the file on the network share if any user is using the application at that time.

I can't use Web Start because I don't have access to a cert for signing the jar.

My current workaround is a separate application that copies the desired app to the user's local machine, launches the application, and then the launcher exits. There is a several second delay from when the launcher app exits and the user's app becomes visible.

Can anyone suggest a better deployment method where I can easily update a central copy of the application, one where Windows XP won't maintain a lock on the file?

Update:
The JSmooth method solves the essential issues. The .exe created by JSmooth is locked while in use, but the .jar files containing the application's functionality can be updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* use Java Web Start, as you can use a self-signed certificate to sign your files.  This will give your users a warning which they can accept once and for all.

I would therefore recommend you going that way, as this is the only standard Java way to do what you want, and it works reasonably well.  With the latest Java 6 update you get a lot of new, useful functionality.

A piece of advice:  When you release a new version, put the jars in a new location so the URL's pointing to the jar-files inside the JNLP-file change!  This is because Java Web Start caches the jar-files and this is the best way we have found to ensure that the cache is accurate.

---

EDIT:  I believe you can also use JSmooth to wrap the Java files in an EXE-file, which transparently extracts the various files on the local computer and executes them there.  This should not lock the original EXE file.  I would, however, recommend you use the Web Start approach.

Comment: Indeed, Web Start was designed for exactly this. The acronym, JNLP, means 'Java Network Launching Protocol'.

Comment: +1 for JWS aka Java Web Start, auto-update, easy distribution of the app from a central location